# Where can you buy Apple earphones?

Tags: audio, headphones, apple-store

On the Apple store there are [EarPods](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD827LL/A/apple-earpods-with-remote-and-mic?fnode=75).

[image]

And there are [In-Ear Headphones](http://store.apple.com/us/product/ME186LL/A/apple-in-ear-headphones-with-remote-and-mic?fnode=75).

[image]

But what if I want to buy the good ol' Earphones?

[image]

I find these to be the most comfortable of them all. Apple appears to still produce them, as they are mentioned on the [Compare iPod Models](http://store.apple.com/us/ipod/compare) page where they are bundled with the iPod Shuffle.

I thought maybe Amazon [would work](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=apple%20oem%20earphones&rh=i:aps,k:apple%20oem%20earphones), but apparently OEM [does](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002TZ5XZ6) [not](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008AC9MZO) [mean](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0064ED1U2) [what it used to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_equipment_manufacturer).

Where can I buy Apple Earphones?

Comment: I'd say you could buy mine, but they've been in my ears.  You don't really want them now.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I would just buy some off eBay. I prefer the old ones too and have bought some from there before which were genuine.

If you're worried about fakes, look up the seller or look at their feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Found lots of places online...

http://m.world-of-accessories.co.uk/genuine-apple-earphones-with-remote-mb770ga-p-1488.html?gclid=COmY79bR2rgCFfLHtAodaR0AvQ

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that those earphones would be more genuine that the ones in the several Amazon OEM listings I linked to?

Comment: I haven't ordered from them myself but personally yes I think they look legit. And there not 4usd.